# Can one use a MySQL query function in the WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

Using a derived value in a MySQL WHERE clause doesn't work.  Is there a way to simulate this behavior?  Below is an example query that fails because of the `WHERE count > 5` line:

```
SELECT
    title,
    company_id,
    count( id ) as count
FROM
    table
WHERE
    count > 5
GROUP BY
    title,
    company_id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aggregates cannot be used in `WHERE`, but rather in `HAVING`.  And you will need to add a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT
    title,
    company_id,
    count( id ) as count
FROM
    table
GROUP BY title, company_id
HAVING count > 5
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use having clause if you want to work with aggregate functions as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

> The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

```
SELECT
  title,
  company_id,
  count( id ) as count
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 
  title, company_id
HAVING
  count > 5
```

**UPDATE:**
In this case, you have to use `HAVING` clause but I wanted to note one thing to keep in mind when using `HAVING` clause. [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) states that:

> The HAVING clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent to the client, with no optimization. (LIMIT is applied after HAVING.)

So, as stated in the same documentation:

> Do not use HAVING for items that should be in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `WHERE` on aggregate column.

Try this:

```
    SELECT
        title,
        company_id,
        count( id ) as cnt
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY title, company_id
    HAVING
        cnt > 5
```